# How to keep two time variables in php from showing their total identical value?

Tags: php, time

I have a leaderboard that would be capable of tracking time played on my game servers. It works 100% in its current format, however I would like to make the "days" measurement more specific, and I am unsure how. Here is the full time function that we'd be working on:

```
function NiceTimeFormat( $seconds ) {
    $mins = floor( $seconds / 60 );
    $hours = floor( $mins / 60 );
    $days = floor( $hours / 24 );

    if ( $days > 0 ) {
        return $days." Days";
    }

    if ( $hours > 0 ) {
        return $hours." Hours";
    }

    if ( $mins > 0 ) {
        return $mins." Mins";
    }

    return $seconds." Seconds";
}
```

Now what happens here is it checks the (in this case, a mysql) database for how many seconds the player has. It measures in seconds, and then goes up from there, which explains the $mins, $hours, and $days statements. The minutes and hours statements can stay just like they are right now, however I would like to add a "leftover hours" measurement to a player that has more than a day played.

Now I don't mean to be captain obvious, but of course the code won't simply do that if I just put:

```
    if ( $days > 0 ) {
        return "{$days} days and {$hours} hours";
    }
```

Here is what I end up with, but is also the exact layout I would like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7bzp.png The only obvious issue is of course, it's basically just stating how many days the player has, and how many hours the player has, both as the same amount of 'time' if you're following me. What I'd like to do to that is to make it so the hours is just a leftover hours. So if the player has 27 hours, it would say something like "1 days and 3 hours" instead of what I currently get with "1 days and 27 hours" which of course is not correct.

So say I'd have an $hoursleftover or $leftover statement that defined the leftover of their time in hours, how would I go about doing that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to make substractions. `24*60*60 = 86400`

```
$days = floor( $seconds / 86400 );
$seconds = $seconds - $days*86400;

$hours = floor( $seconds / 3600 );
$seconds = $seconds - $hours *3600;

$mins = floor( $seconds / 60 );
$seconds = $seconds - $mins * 60;
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick perfectly. Thank you and anyone else that responded for the help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

What you're asking for is...modulus! The magical % I believe.

Given a set of seconds, here's what I suggest you do:

```
<?php
$s = '134324';
$seconds = $s%60;
$s = $s - $seconds;
$minutes = ($s%3600)/60;
$s = $s -$minutes*60;
$hours = ($s%86400)/3600;
$s = $s -$hours*3600;
$days = $s/86400;
echo $days.' Days ' .$hours.' Hours '.$minutes.' Minutes '.$seconds.' Seconds';
?>
```

I have set up a working example [here](https://accretion.us/stackoverflow/28956100.php) using php's time()